# Jquery ajax how to update html element without listening for updates every x second?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to check new updates in the database without using setInterval? The problem is that I want to update the video source in the video tag but if I check for update every second, then my video will keep refreshing. I just want the video to refresh if the database is updated. For example, If I have a cat video in the current_video column in database, then the cat video should play. Otherwise, if I update the video to dog video, only then will the video element change to dog video.

```
$.get("/musicmania/playing/getCurrentSongDir", function(data, status){
    setInterval(function(){
            $("#video").html("<source src='/musicmania/app/resources/"   
            + data + "' type='video/mp4'></source>");
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add if statement and check if old data and the new one are not equal then refresh the video.
Your code will look something like this.

```
var old_data='';
$.get("/musicmania/playing/getCurrentSongDir", function(data, status){
   if( old_data != data ) {
       $("#video").html("<source src='/musicmania/app/resources/"   
        + data + "' type='video/mp4'></source>");
   }
   old_data = data;
});
```

If you want to do it via ajax technology you have to send request every 'x' seconds. But there is another technology called [websockets](http://socketo.me/).
You can use websockets if you don't want to open connection to server side every 'x' seconds.